# String contains NUL bytes

Tags: ruby, encode

I'm trying to decode this file that is in `IBM437` into readable `UTF` I'm at the point where I think I've almost got it but I'm getting an `ArgumentError` where the string contains `nul` bytes, I'm aware of how to `gsub` out `nul` bytes using:
`.gsub("\u0000", '')` however I can't figure out where to `gsub` the bytes out.

Here's the source:

```
def gather_info
  file = './lib/SETI_message.txt'
  File.read(file).each_line do |gather|
    packed = [gather].pack('b*')
    ec = Encoding::Converter.new(packed, 'utf-8')
    encoding_forced = packed.encode(ec)
    File.open('packed.txt', 'a+'){ |s| s.puts(encoding_forced.gsub("\u0000", '')) }
  end
end

gather_info
```

And here's the [file](http://www2.mps.mpg.de/homes/heller/downloads/files/SETI_message.txt)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not set the `encoding` option on your `File` read?

Comment: @tadman What do you mean?'

Comment: That looks like [quite a fun challenge](http://www2.mps.mpg.de/homes/heller/downloads/files/SETI_rules.txt), but you’re on the wrong track trying to decode as IBM437. Check out the hints given.

Comment: Is the resulting file supposed to be human-readable, or is it a data file of some sort?

Comment: @matt The encoding o the file is already IBM437, I'm trying to decide it from 7 bit to 8 bit, I never saw the hints till now lol, I'll post the full length program on code review when I finish it.

Comment: @13aal the default encoding on your computer is IBM437, that’s why Ruby says the file has that encoding. The data is a series of images. Here’s a spoiler, the fifth image looks like this: http://imgur.com/P1hTc8h

Comment: @matt How'd you come up with that did you use the prime numbers to decode it?

Comment: @13aal it’s just from doing what the hints suggest. There are 7 images, each 359 by 757 pixels. I used [ChunkyPNG](http://chunkypng.com/) to create the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me :

```
file = File.read('SETI.txt')
packed = file.scan(/......../).map{|s| s.to_i(2)}.pack('U*')
File.write('packed.txt', packed)
```

Let's break `file.scan(/......../).map{|s| s.to_i(2)}.pack('U*')` down :

1. `file.scan(/......../)`

Here we break the huge string of 0s and 1s (the file) into an array of strings containing 8 characters each. It looks like that : ['00001111', '11110000', ...].

2. `arr.map{|s| s.to_i(2)}`

From step 1 we got an array of strings representing the different characters in binary notation. We can convert one of those strings (called `s`) by applying `s.to_i(2)` because the parameter '2' says to the method to_i to use base 2. So `'00000011'.to_i(2)` returns 3.

We apply this to all the characters by using `map`.
So we now have an array that looks like `[98, 82, 49, 39, ...]`.

3. `arr.pack('U*')`

From step 2 we have an array of integers representing each a character. We can now use the pack method to transform our array of integers into a string. The parameter we use for pack is U to tell him that the integers are in fact UTF-8 characters.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks for breaking it down like that